# What does a question mark over a blue folder icon mean?

Tags: icons, terminal.app, anaconda

I use `conda` to manage virtual environments for my coding projects. I have a specific environment that when activate through the Terminal app will make the following icon appear on top:

[image]

This is right at the top bar on the Terminal app. What does it mean?

Comment: [macos - Why does the folder icon in my Terminal have a question mark overlaid? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75751/why-does-the-folder-icon-in-my-terminal-have-a-question-mark-overlaid)